# RavenDB Facet Null_Value

Tags: c#, ravendb, faceted-search

I have a scenario where by I'm saving variations of the same document. Some of the document properties are optional and so will naturally be stored as NULL.

Please could someone advise how to prevent FacetResults from returning/counting NULL_VALUE in the results?

My Index looks like this:

```
public class ListingsIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Listing>
{
    public ListingsIndex()
    {
        Map = listings => listings
            .Select(listing => new
        {
            category = listing.Category,
            make = listing.Make,
            size = listing.Size // Size may sometimes be NULL                
        });            
    }
}
```

So to clarify, I would like to return all documents for a certain "Make" for example and then filter the results further by selecting "Size" values in my Faceted navigation which should not include NULL_VALUE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **Where** condition after **Select** to filter the size:

```
   Map = listings => listings
        .Select(listing => new
    {
        category = listing.Category,
        make = listing.Make,
        size = listing.Size // Size may sometimes be NULL                
    }).Where(e => e.Size != null);
```